# If $X$ is a metric, then $X$ is compact if and only if $X$ is sequentially compact

Tags: elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces, compactness, proof-explanation

I'm going through a proof for the theorem:

> If $X$ is a metric, then $X$ is compact if and only if $X$ is sequentially compact.

I'm trying to understand the easier forward direction but I'm having a hard time understanding where we've pulled/created a subsequence in this. So the proof goes like this:

Let $x_n$ be a sequence, and let $A_n = \{x_n, x_{n+1}, \ldots\}$ be a nested sequence of nonempty sets.
Let $F_n = \overline{A_n}$ be nested and nonempty.
By a corollary, the [FIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_intersection_property) holds, so $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty F_n \neq \varnothing$.

Let $x \in \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty F_n$. Then $x \in F_1 = \overline{A_1}$, so $B(x,1) \cap A_1 \neq \varnothing$.

Then $\exists n_1 \geq 1$ such that $x_{n_1} \in B(x,1)$.

How is this last line deduced?

Comment: What does $B(x,1) \cap A_1 \neq \varnothing$ mean?

Comment: Just look at what $A_1$ actually is.

Comment: @DanielFischer That the ball around a point $x$ in the closure of the sequence $A_1$ also intersects the sequence itself?

Comment: Well, yes. So, there must be a point of the sequence in the ball.

Comment: It means there is a point, call it $y$ for the moment that lies in the intersection. In particular, $y\in A_1$. Now look at the definition of $A_n$.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp Just drew a picture and it became a lot easier to understand... thanks to the both of you for pressing that point!

Comment: If some sort of answer can be posted I can accept it and close this up (unless you feel that I still haven't understood it, but I think I have now!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $x\in \overline{A_{1}}$ then the statement $B(x,1)\cap A_{1}\neq\emptyset$ follows from the definition of closure. But since $A_{1}=\{x_{1},x_{2},...\}$ then this can be rewritten as $B(x,1)\cap \{x_{1},x_{2},...\}\neq\emptyset$. Finally, by the definition of intersection we can conclude that there exists $n_{1}\geq 1$ such that $x_{n_{1}}\in B(x,1)$.

Comment: Thanks for using \overline rather than \bar, was struggling to recall what a nicer looking command would be.

Comment: @IrregularUser: Sure! \overline looks nicer for sets and wider statements, I think \bar is mostly useful for individual lowercase letters (e.g. the conjugate of a complex number $z$ written as $\bar{z}$ with \bar).