# compact $\Leftrightarrow$ sequentially compact $\Leftrightarrow$ totally bounded and complete

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness, axiom-of-choice

Let $X$ be a metric space. Assuming the axiom of countable choice, the following are equivalent:

1. $X$ is compact.
2. $X$ is sequentially compact.
3. $X$ is totally bounded and complete.

What if we don't assume the axiom of countable choice?

I think $1\Rightarrow 3$ holds, but I don't know the rest.

Comment: Have you searched the site? These topics were asked several times already.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1686252/if-x-is-a-metric-then-x-is-compact-if-and-only-if-x-is-sequentially-compa should give you an example with a non-compact, but sequentially compact which is also totally bounded and complete.

Comment: Some results from Herrlich's book [starting with Theorem 3.27](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=_0cDCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA37) might be interesting for you.

Comment: What is your issue with AC?

Comment: @Math1000 I don't think AC is true. I want to do mathematics without it.

Comment: I think you will run into more problems rejecting AC than you will accepting it. It is true that some conjectures are true/false independently of AC, but AC makes certain things a lot easier.

Comment: Ponta, *why* do you think that AC is false? I mean, what would be the philosophical backing of this approach? Not to mention that your other question essentially asks if you can do the same mathematics as in ZFC by simply requiring that all the objects are "well-behaved enough" to not necessitate choice in the outset universe, which does not *really* circumvent any real use of AC anyway...

Comment: @AsafKaragila I do not think AC is true or false because I think it is not self-evidently true and I have no counterexample of it, so I cannot accept neither it nor its negation as an axiom.

Comment: Cantor believed it to be self-evident ("Gedankegesetz" I believe he called it, a law of thought).. (for the idea that all sets can be well-ordered, which he used in a proof).